# Express server hangs after second page load or refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My Express server hangs for some reason whenever the page is refreshed. A check of the debug log shows the following lines are causing major lags:

```
express:router dispatching GET / +16s
express:router dispatching GET /o/jquery.js +35s
```

How are simple `GET` events slowing down the page on the second load, but not on the first load? I downloaded jQuery to internalize my dependencies.

The simplified code that does not depend on the database is hosted on [my GitHub.](https://github.com/lincolnanders/part-manager/tree/SLOWDOWN)

You can download my repo and then install dependencies from my `package.json` and then run my `server.js` file. The webpage will run at [localhost:4000](http://localhost:4000). Just refreshing the page will cause it to hang, showing where the problem is. The problem should be somewhere inside my `server.js`, `routing/api.js`, `routing/modules.js`, or `routing/front-end.js` file.

Comment: Per the stack overflow rules, code that is necessary to understand the question must be pasted into the question itself and formatted appropriately, not only available via an external link.  This is because external links have a habit of disappearing or getting changed, rendering the question a worthless reference for future readers.

Comment: For starters, why are you using `app` objects as routers instead of using a router object?

Comment: Same as @jfriend00 read your logs. That's not how you create routers.

Comment: What is `gen_modules()` in `routing/front-end.js` trying to do?  It seems possible that the second time it's called, it messes something up because you are accumulating state each time it is called.  I even wonder if the `while` loop might be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that your `while` loop in `gen_modules()` turns into an infinite loop the second time you call it.  This is the operative part of the code:

```
    var rand_url = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^\w]+/g, '').substring(16);

    while (exports.rand_urls[rand_url]) {
        // Regenerate random strings until there are no matches. Should be reletively fast.
        rand_url = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^\w]+/g, '').substring(16);
    }
```

The problem is that `.substring(16)` starts at the 16th character and gives you the rest of the string from there which will result in an empty string (perhaps you meant to use `.substring(0,16)`.  So, after you populate the first `exports.rand_urls[rand_url]` value, you keep trying to find another unique one, but you're making the same empty string over and over again so you never find a unique one, thus the `while` loop never exits.

There's really no reason to truncate the string at all.  You can just leave it as:

```
    var rand_url = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^\w]+/g, '');

    while (exports.rand_urls[rand_url]) {
        // Regenerate random strings until there are no matches. Should be reletively fast.
        rand_url = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^\w]+/g, '');
    }
```

Or, if you want to truncate it, you can start it at the 0th index:

```
    var rand_url = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^\w]+/g, '').substring(0, 16);

    while (exports.rand_urls[rand_url]) {
        // Regenerate random strings until there are no matches. Should be reletively fast.
        rand_url = Math.random().toString(36).replace(/[^\w]+/g, '').substring(0, 16);
    }
```

Comment: This is it, thank you! I started instead at the 0th index as you pointed out and there is no more hang!